# JQuery datepicker does not load in all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load [JQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in two text fields, so I am using the following code

```
$(function() {
     $('#DOB, #SignupDate').datepicker();
});
```

and here is the HTML for both fields:

```
<div class="field field_input">
<label for="DOB">D.O.B</label>
<input type="text" name="DOB" value="">
</div>

<div class="field field_input">
<label for="SignupDate">Signup Date</label>
<input type="text" name="SignupDate" value="">
</div>
```

It is loading just fine in the DOB field but it is not loading in the SignupDate field. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here and how to solve it?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Shouldn't it be id instead of name? `<input type="text" id="SignupDate" value="">` and for the other one too. `#` matches an id selector, not name

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: I'm surprised it works for either.

Comment: Thanks all, I am really not sure how I missed the id, but thanks to you all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to select the #DOB and #SignupDate.

```
 $('#DOB, #SignupDate')
```

It means get element by id DOB and SignupDate but you have no element with id="DOB" nor
id="SignupDate"

So please use

```
<input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB" value="">        //<- note id="DOB"
<input type="text" id="SignupDate" name="SignupDate" value=""> //<- note id="SignupDate"
```

Comment: I am not sure how I missed the id! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `id` attribute on your inputs. Two reasons:

1. In your jQuery code, `#` indicates an `id` selector, not a `name` selector.
2. The `for` attribute on the labels should correspond with an `id` attribute on another element, not the `name` attribute.

Given that this is probably a form, you still want to keep the `name` attribute, but you probably just want a matching `id` attribute.